# Why does css nth-child selector not work?

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is show the menu when mouse pointer over the first link, if I use `.show:hover .menu` it's OK, but if I use nth-child, not work.

Specially, if I use `nth-child(1)`, the link will fill the whole line, like become a block element itself, not its child, `nth-child(2)` then 
not action.

This is all code:

```css
.show {
  position: relative;
}

.show:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
}


/* not work */

.show:hover:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}


/* work */

.show:hover .menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 0px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #333
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="show">11111
        <div class="menu">
        </div>
      </a>
  <a href="#">22222</a>
  <a href="#">33333</a>
  <a href="#">44444</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to select? If `.menu`, what *is* wrong with `.show:hover .menu`?

Comment: It is clearly written in docs; _"`nth-child` matches elements based on their position in a group of **siblings**"_, and `menu` is not a `show` sibling, it is a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current-element:nth-child(n)` pseudo selector is looking if the current-element is such an *nth-child*, it is not targeting at a child of the current-element.

So your `.show:hover:nth-child(2)` will match any element which has the class show and is hovered and is the second child of its parent.

Your markup doesn't have any element that can fit there, since the only element matching `.show` is the first child of its parent.

And when you used `.show:hover:nth-child(1)` you were actually matching the anchor `<a>`.

What you want is `.show:hover > :nth-child(1)` with a child selector `>` to actually target its direct children:

```css
.show {
  position:relative;  
}

.show:hover {
  background-color:#f00;
}

/* works */
.show:hover > :nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  left:0px;
  top:20px;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#333
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="show">11111
    <div class="menu">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">22222</a>
  <a href="#">33333</a>
  <a href="#">44444</a>
</div>
```